# jquery ui autosuggest with values form database not working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make jquery ui auto suggest work by returning array of values from php and populate it.

here is my code:

**html:**

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search user..."/>
```

**jquery:**

```
  $(function() {
      $("#search").on("keyup",function(){
          $.get("searchterm.php",{searchterm:$(this).val()},function(data){
              $("#search").autocomplete({
                  source: data
               });
          });
      });                    
  });
```

**searchterm.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

include 'includes/initialize.php';

if(isset($_GET["searchterm"])){
    $search = $_GET["searchterm"];
    $result = $db->query_db("select * from users where username like '%$search%'");
    $out = "";
    $i=0;
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    while ($row = $db->fetch_array($result)) {
        $i++;
        if($num_rows == $i){
            $out .= '"'.$row['username'].'"';
        }else{
            $out .= '"'.$row['username'].'",';
        }
   }
   echo "[".$out."]";
}
```

php code it working perfectly fine and returning it in the following format:

["user1","user2"] based on the query string passed.

but i am not getting the desired result. please someone help me solve this.

Comment: What do you get if you do console.log(data) in the callback function of the AJAX call?

Comment: ["administrator","susheel61","susheel62"] based on the query it returns fine...

Comment: for some reason it is getting appended this way :
GET http://localhost/project/[%22susheel61%22,%22susheel62%22]?term=su and getting error

Comment: With your current structure you are instantiating autocomplete with EVERY keyup event, this is not how autocomplete is designed to work. I will post with an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your autocomplete has to be defined only one time.

Also, you should consider using json to parse data

```
$('#search').autocomplete(
{
   delay: 1000,
   source: fctSource
});

var fctSource = function(request, response) 
{
   $.getJSON(
         'searchterm.php',
         { searchterm: request.term },
         function(data, status, xhr) 
         {
            response(data);
         }
   );
}
```

And then, in your php, do like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
// ...
echo json_encode(your_array_of_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you properly get data from a remote source:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'searchterm.php',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            data: $('#search').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
}).on('click change keypress keyup keydown blur focus paste', function (e) {
    // Do what you want with event handlers here or remove completely because autocomplete already binds the keyup event
});
```

Comment: Make sure to use the latest edit, I had to remove a bunch of stuff specifically coded for my web app